# 3 Activities in Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made 2 Activities and started a second activity by clicking on a `Button`. All is good...

But if I add third activity - nothing works - I can't start neither the second activity, nor the third activity...

Program scheme:

1. First Activity has a Button, which starts the second Activity
2. Second Activity has a Button, which starts the third Activity

Comment: You should explain more your problem. Showing some code may let someone find the solution.

Comment: make sure you have added third activity in manifast. and post log when your app is crashing

Comment: You should post your code and also make sure all three Activities are described in the Manifest file.

Comment: Make sure you've initialized all views that you used.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't really be a problem if you have written it correctly. I recommand taking a quick look on the tutorial about creating a basic program in the training guide released by the Android developer team. They give you an idea on how to make the first button, just add this method to your second button instead of receiving text back.
As mentioned above, we need more details and you should also check your manifest file.
There isn't really much more we can help you with when you give us these details. Sorry.